# Security advantages: check_by_ssh versus check_nrpe

Tags: ssh, security, nagios, nrpe

The question is which is more secure - as opposed to which is better from a configuration standpoint.

I have a number of Centos and Debian systems. The NRPE daemon is installed and working on all them, with `nrpe.conf` configured with `allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,<Nagios_monitoring_server_IP>`. The client's NRPE default port only allows Nagios_monitoring_server_IP through iptables as well. All the checks from the Nagios monitoring server use `check_nrpe`.

Is the above the most secure, or is it better to use `check_by_ssh` with a key instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check_nrpe` is not secure, unless you configure and use certificates, if not you are using "Anonymous Diffie-Hellman" [see OpenSSL wiki for an explanation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Diffie_Hellman).

NRPE's security is based on IP whitelisting only, so not safe against MITM attacks as well...

`check_by_ssh` uses the same security as any SSH connection and is safe on a trust on first use logic (when the host key is added to known_hosts)

This is why Icinga 2's cluster protocol is built on [TLS with certificates](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#security).

Comment: Just for clarification - since an NRPE server only requests that the client system run a script that already exists on the client system and must be configured within the client's nrpe.conf, and then sends the output of that script back to the server - what kind of MitM attacks could be exploited?

Comment: 1) Sniffing data, 2) Injecting data when arguments are allowed and 3) Manipulating results